# Safari caches JSONP requests locally

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, safari, jsonp

I have a page that makes the same JSONP request multiple times in a single page load.  In most browsers this works fine, but Safari caches the response locally until such time as the page is reloaded.  Even when I send back a Cache-Control: no-cache header on the response.

consider the following example code:

```
var plcbCnt = 0;
var plcb = "plcb" + plcbCnt;
while(window[plcb]){
    plcb = "plcb" + (++plcbCnt);
}

$.ajax({
    "url": "http://myserver.com/echoDate",
    "dataType": 'jsonp',
    "jsonp": "cb",
    "jsonpCallback": plcb,
    "success": function(resp){
        $("#pants").html($("#pants").html() + resp + "<br/>");
    }
});
```

First request returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/javascript
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=g0zwq2qiaheh4145cudddmjo; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 20 Oct 2010 18:22:12 GMT

plcb0('634231777326425375');
```

Subsequent calls serve from the local cache, rather than hitting the server like they should.

You're probably wondering what that extra part at the beginning is about setting the callback function.  I could just use a random number there, right?
Not really.  We avoid extra rendering work by caching the entire output, based on the requested URL.  So if I change the callback function name on each request, I lose the benefits of the server cache.

Best I can think of is to add a garbage parameter on the request, and make the server cache strip that out of the URL when making the cache key.  But I wanted to see if there was a better option first... something about Safari that I don't know about.

Comment: Why are you are not using getJSON? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ Does the same thing in the end.

Comment: getJSON doesn't have the flexibility to define the callback the way I'm doing.  Relies on the default setting, which creates a random number each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems it happens on IE also, you can set cache to false in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({  
    /*cache: false,*/
    "url": "http://myserver.com/echoDate",
    "dataType": 'jsonp',
    "jsonp": "cb",
    "jsonpCallback": plcb,
    "success": function(resp){
        $("#pants").html($("#pants").html() + resp + "<br/>");
    }
});
```

Comment: cache=false just adds the garbage parameter that I mentioned at the end of my question.
(at least, I think that's all it does)

Comment: (double checked jQuery source.  that's all it does)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a hash parameter - the browser will see this as a new request, and won't use its cache, but everything beyond the hash gets stripped out before the request is made. Give this a whirl and see it it works:

```
var callback = '#call' + new Date().getTime();
$.ajax({
    "url": "http://myserver.com/echoDate" + callback,
    "dataType": 'jsonp',
    "jsonp": "cb",
    "jsonpCallback": plcb,
    "success": function(resp){
        $("#pants").html($("#pants").html() + resp + "<br/>");
    }
});
```